# How to debug PowerShell Scripts which are executed via GPO during startup?

Tags: windows, active-directory, powershell, group-policy

I have a Powershell Script which install and updates Software via the Windows Package Manager [Chocolatey](http://chocolatey.org).

If I execute my PS-Script as a user, everything is fine. So there has to be another issue like an restricting Execution Policy (this is set to unrestricted via GPO).

How do I get the Output of the Powershell? I am using Start-Transcript but I cannot find the output file anywhere and if I specify the path it doesn't create the log file...

The Powershell-Script executes during startup as machine GPO.

Are there other options to debug, I havent thought of?

Comment: Where you output it ? I suggest the temp folder to prevent access error

Comment: C:\output.txt I thought of an access error, but Powershell scripts executed by machine GPO should have local administrator privileges or am I wrong?

Comment: It would be, but I wanted to be sure its not in a share access the log. Does your new gpo run? gpresult /h:t.htm

Comment: Yes it does. I think it is an issue with chocolatey running under the local system account. So getting the output Is the goal I think.

Comment: maybe create a new test gpo, create a .bat that will start your powershell command with the output to text in the .bat (./ps.ps1 >>c:\test.txt) You will see the error powershell might give

Comment: Okay I think we got the error. There is a Security Question which ask if the Powershell Script should be executed. It thinks it is downloaded from the Internet. The error message says I have to use the Cmdlet Unblock-File to prevent the security question.

Comment: [Powershell Security Warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728143/ignore-security-warning-running-script-from-command-line) I will try to bypass this security warning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem was very stupid... I had added the Powershell Script in the Scripts Section not in the Powershell Scripts Section while in the Properties of Startup-Scripts...

I found out, that Start-Transcript does not create a logfile when executed as SYSTEM-Account (during Startup). You have to specify a path, then it creates the logfile. Sorry and thank you for your help.

Answer (score -2):

Start-Transcript -Path "$($env:windir)\Temp\Logon.txt" -Force

[Your Content]

Stop-Transcript

Comment: This doesn't look helpful at all, but OP didn't specify his not working code, so this would be a working example, neverless.